# Sata mode keeps changing to RST (dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, ahci

I use Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 as a dual boot system.

Every now and then (about every second month) the Sata mode is changed from AHCI to RST without me entering the BIOS. Can that happen after Windows updates etc.?

I get a blue screen then so I have to follow these steps (https://mauriceneumann.de/ahci-modus-nachtraeglich-in-windows-10-aktivieren/) to change SATA mode back to AHCI without Windows crashing.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Google gives limited ideas, this is about as close as I could find with a quick search.  Does not help much.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Lenovo/comments/geevha/change_bios_update_to_respect_storage_controller/

Comment: UEFI updates which you should do, often reset UEFI settings to defaults. And Windows (and Linux) can do UEFI updates which you may not see as part of other updates. Windows also turns its fast start up back on. My motherboard only updates manually, but I keep a list of settings I need to redo in UEFI.

Comment: Okay, I guess updates are the problem then.. any idea how I stop updates changing my sata mode settings?